# Firefox extension: background script automatically stop working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing an extension for firefox but I have an issue that I can not figure out a solution and I hope somebody can help me.

I have a content script and a background script and I have to use both.
When i load the script throught about:debugging everything starts fine, as you can see on the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UjwW.png)
As you can see, it's wrote in italian, the background script is executing.

After a while, like 15 seconds, the background script it's blocked automatically, as you can see in the follow picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kA2W.png)

Does anybody knows how to do to not block the background script?

Thank you very much!

I tried to add browser_specific_settings in manifest.json and also make the background script light to not use a lot of resources, but it didn't work and the background script still doesn't work after a while.

Edit:
Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Description",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "checker.js" ]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "options_ui": {
    "page": "settings/options.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "email@domain.ch",
      "strict_min_version": "42.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your background script is not persistent. Show your manifest.json.